# calling webservice using php

Tags: java, php, webservice-client

I am  new to PHP and wanted to write a snippet of code which would call a Webservice.
I have the java equivalent code for it that works correctly.

```
HttpClient client=new HttpClient();
GetMethod method=new GetMethod(URL);
method.addRequestHeader("test1","test1");
String statusCode=client.executeMethod();
if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
       System.err.println("Method failed: " + method.getStatusLine());
}
// Read the response body.
byte[] responseBody = method.getResponseBody();
// Deal with the response.
// Use caution: ensure correct character encoding and is not binary data
System.out.println(new String(responseBody));
```

Comment: what type or web service? Also have you done any prior research into PHP + your webservice type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of different ways to do it.

If you're just trying to send a simple GET request, [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) will work just fine. (Note: you can also do POST requests with `file_get_contents` in conjunction with `stream_context_create`, but there are other ways I find nicer)

Example:

```
$response = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/webservice?foo=bar&baz=1");
```

Another method is to use [`cURL`](http://php.net/curl). This may not be available on all systems (but should be on most). Here's an example of a POST request using curl:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/webservice');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('foo'=>'bar','baz'=>1)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Alternatively, another way is to use the PEAR package [HTTP_Request2](http://pear.php.net/package/http_request2). This will work on all systems and can be a nice way to do it. For more information and examples, see the [manual page](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-request2.request.php).

Comment: is there a way to send a GET request using curl. I also wanted to know how do you add headers to the request.

Comment: @frictionlesspulley It sends a GET request by default. Doing `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1)` tells it to do a post request instead. To send headers, use the following format: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: text-plain', 'Content-length: 100', ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Your should use some webservice dedicated methods, it would be easier. For example if your webservice is a SOAP one : http://php.net/manual/fr/book.soap.php, or an XML-RPC : http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlrpc.php

Answer (score 0):

Look at httprequest-send in php, that should get you started in terms of building the right request.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.httprequest-send.php